# Topology change: star to hierachical?

Tags: omnet++, hierarchical-clustering, adhoc, inet, topology

I'm not familiar with omnet and adhoc network.
I have investigated many papers, theses, books and tutorials (ex: Tictoc, inet framework..).
Therefore, I worry that this work has been for a long time.

Now I have to simulate the different topology from star to hierarchical for testing.
Is there any topology generator tool for this (ex:ReaSE)?
Or I have to configure the detailed information (ex:Adhoc network routing) ?

**Objective**
 - Performance: Test different topology for Device to Device communication using WiFi-Direct

**My Environment**
 - INET 3.2.4
 - OMNeT++4.6
 - Ubuntu 16.04

**References**
 - Paper:https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1609/1609.04604.pdf 
 - Source code: 
   https://www-phare.lip6.fr/~trnguyen/research/wifidirect/

Thank you very much again.
Have a nice day and with all the best wishes. :D

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Neddemo is a good example of topology. : D

Answer (score 0):

The NED language in OMNeT++ is specifically designed to describe various topologies. Take a look at the `samples/neddemo` example.